# You're not much use to me. Meaning

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of "You're not much use to me". I couldn't find the meaning of it anywhere on internet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a situation where someone is expected to do something for you and fail, you can say **"You were not (of) much use to me"**, it's pretty rough though.

Another example: **"Crying is not much use to me now, she's already gone."** She has already left and crying won't make things change, go after her.

Answer (score 1):

Saying "*X* is not much *Y*" or "*X* is not very *Y*" are understated ways of saying "*X* **is not** *Y.*"

For example, saying "it's not very good" is a (somewhat more polite) way of saying "it's bad." You could say "there was not much snow" to mean "there was only a little snow."

In this case,  "You're not much use to me" means "you're useless to me."